# Error mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean

Tags: php

Tengo un error con esta linea de mi programa, dice que le falta un parametro

mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean

este es la linea que me dice que tengo error

```
fwrite($arch, "<table:table table:name=\"".$this- 
>nombre_tabla($tabla)."\" table:style-name=\"ta1\"><table:table-column 
table:style-name=\"co1\" table:number-columns- 
repeated=\"".mysqli_num_rows($conexion->query("select * from                                                  
".$tabla))."\" table:default-cell-style-name=\"Default\" />");
```

Comment: Agrega tu codigo, de otra forma es muy dificil ayudarte

Comment: Lo siento, aqui esta el codigo

Comment: fwrite($arch, "<table:table table:name=\"".$this->nombre_tabla($tabla)."\" table:style-name=\"ta1\"><table:table-column table:style-name=\"co1\" table:number-columns-repeated=\"".mysqli_num_rows($conexion->query("select * from ".$tabla))."\" table:default-cell-style-name=\"Default\" />");

Comment: @FranciscoCardenas mete el código en tu pregunta, edítala y agregalo

Comment: Si me da otros errores el sistema se los hago saber para que me apoyen, gracias

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar separar las operaciones asi:

```
$resultado = $conexion->query("select * from ".$tabla);
fwrite($arch, "<table:table table:name=\"".$this->nombre_tabla($tabla)."\" 
table:style-name=\"ta1\"><table:table-column table:style-name=\"co1\" 
table:number-columns-repeated=\"".mysqli_num_rows($resultado)."\" 
table:default-cell-style-name=\"Default\" />");
```